# How can I check the video/audio format for a MKV file?

Tags: windows-7, video, software-rec, audio, codec

I have a MKV video file. Can you please tell me how I can find out the video/audio codec of that file, and how I can find out if it is 1080p or 1080i?

I have a Windows 7 desktop PC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could always install [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). It plays almost every format. Hit Ctrl+J while something's playing and it will show you the Codec info.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to find every possible info about the given media file.
(There is a GUI, and a CLI version too.)

[image: MediaInfo Example Screeny]

Comment: [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot) became obsolete; MediaInfo is fine. +1.